# How to put brand name just to the right of logo in html?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am making a webpage and i want that the name of the brand should appear right next to the brand logo, just to the right of the brand logo. I have tried using the float-left property but nothing is doing good.

I have provided both the html as well as css sheet, plz someone help. And if possible try to fix this without using flex-box.

Here's my code:

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #61122f;
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
}

#header-nav {
  background-color: gold;
}

#logo-img {
  background: url("BurgerKING1.png") no-repeat;
  width: 152px;
  height: 152px;
  margin: 10px 15px 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>DEV RESTAURANT TESTING</title>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="testing.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Exo:ital,wght@0,900;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>


  <header>
    <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a href="testing.html" class="float-left">
            <div id="logo-img" alt="logo image"></div>
          </a>
          <div class="navbar-brand ">
            <a href="testing.html">
              <h1>Burger King</h1>
            </a>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: remove float and use this .navbar-header { display: flex;}

Comment: _And if possible try to fix this without using flex-box._ Why?

Comment: It looks like all you need to do is add `float: left` to the element with classname "float-left".  Can you be more specific about what's not working the way you expect?

Comment: @DanielBeck OP is trying to use the `float` utilities that are included with Bootstrap 5. However, `float-left` isn't the correct class name anymore. It's `float-start`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a typo, [since reading the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/float/#overview) for the `float` utilities would have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `.navbar-image` (I added a class name) and `.navbar-brand` both float left, then give `.navbar-brand` a margin-top to center it vertically:

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #61122f;
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
}

#header-nav {
  background-color: gold;
}

#logo-img {
  background: url("https://placekitten.com/200/200") no-repeat;
  width: 152px;
  height: 152px;
  margin: 10px 15px 10px 0;
}

.navbar-image, .navbar-brand{
  float: left;
}

.navbar-brand{
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<header>
  <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href="testing.html" class="navbar-image float-left">
          <div id="logo-img" alt="logo image"></div>
        </a>
        <div class="navbar-brand ">
          <a href="testing.html">
            <h1>Burger King</h1>
          </a>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: OP is asking for a "non-flexbox" answer (not sure why), but it's really a typo issue, since `float-left` is not a utility class in BS5. It's now `float-start`.

Comment: @disinfor Right, see my edit!

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
.float-left{
    float: left
}
.navbar-brand {
    float: left 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at your code and you can achieve that by using flexbox and its property justify-content: flex-start, add below properties to your style sheet -

```
.navbar-header{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
```